# Is it possible to replicate a collection in MongoDB

Tags: replication, mongodb

I would like to replicate/synchronize a collection named "CollectionA" from a mongoDB "DataBaseA" to a mongoDB "DatabaseB" in real-time

1. DatabaseB is a normal database (not shared and not a replica)
2. The DatabaseB will have writes to it, but not for collection "CollectionA"
3. The synchronization/replication should be done in real-time with a delay defined based on network latency

I'm trying to achieve this without writing any custom code. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is your MongoDB server version... Solution is use method ["Change Streams"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) or ["Oplog tailing"](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters#:%7E:text=Tailing%20a%20MongoDB%20collection%2C%20or,happening%20in%20the%20entire%20database.)
Where you are "listening" changes of source DB and replicating those commands to destination DB (at other MongoDB installation)

Comment: The Change Streams API is definitely the recommended approach in modern versions of MongoDB (3.6+). Change Streams rely on the replication oplog, but provide a stable API including considerations like durability (only majority-committed changes), security (uses collection-level RBAC), and ordering for change events in a sharded cluster. For some important characteristics of Change Streams, see: [An Introduction to Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams).